# Edit button item not showing up on navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to add an edit button on the navigation bar, but without success. It seems to be a simple task like said on apple documentation [navigation controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW1).

> myViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [myViewController editButtonItem];

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

 //   [self retrievePassengerInformation];

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

[image]

By any reason the edit button is not showing up. Just to let you all know this is a static grouped tableview.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,
Marcos

Comment: When does `editButtonItem` actually get initialized, and what is its type?

Comment: @MikeD this a property returned by the UIViewController object.  

- (UIBarButtonItem *)editButtonItem

Comment: @vilelam Is your view controller inside of a `UINavigationController` or did you just add a `UINavigationBar` to the top of the view?

Comment: Now I understand what’s happening. This ViewController wasn’t called from a navigation controller so the self.navigationItem should not be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

The ViewController wasn’t called from a navigation controller so the self.navigationItem should not be accessed. I ended up creating a outlet to my added UINavigationItem and it's working.

```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *addedNavigationItem;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

 //   [self retrievePassengerInformation];

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.


    self.addedNavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editMethodName:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
```